# jquery validate condition on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I would like to code a validation on button radio. (yes or no). Thanks.
my code :

```
conditions : {
    required : {
        depends: function(element) {
            if ($('#conditions')val('Yes').is(':checked')){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: yes i wanted to taste if Yes or Not. If Not errors message it yes passed. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to return wether or not the radio with the value `"Yes"` is checked or not, and since ID's are unique, we'd assume that radio button has the ID `#conditions`

```
conditions : {
    required : {
        depends: function(element) {
            return $('#conditions').is(':checked');
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. Your solution help me.

Answer (score 0):

Give UniqueId to the YES radio button, and use the code below :

```
if ($('#uniqueid').prop("checked")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

In Short :

```
return $('#uniqueid').prop("checked")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's work but I get error message  with return true and false.